# How can I safely check user input in sql and echo if available or not on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a html form where a user is expected to select a keyword that must not exist in the database. Just like checking if a domain exist.

If the keyword exist, i want to echo on the same page (on top of the input field.) that the keyword is available or not.

**Edit 1**

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$email = clean($_POST['email']);

//Input Validations
if($email == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//Check for duplicate login ID
if($email != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email already in use';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: register-form.php");
    exit();
}

if() {
    header("location: samepage.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login Form</title>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
    echo '<ul class="err">';
    foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
        echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
}
?>
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="register-exec.php">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <th>First Name </th>
  <td><input name="email" type="text" class="textfield" id="email" /></td>
</tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what to do in the last if statement of the php. Can anyone help me with this code?

**Edit 2**

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

require_once('config.php');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(count($_POST) > 0){
//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

$email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

if($email == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email already in use';
    $errflag = true;
} 
else 
{
    $errflag = false; // if record not exist.
}

}

$conn->close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login Form</title>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
if($errflag){
echo implode(",", $errmsg_arr); // if any error found print error array and use your error stuff like redirection as you are using.
}
else{ 
echo "Available"; // else print Available message or use your stuff.
} 
?>
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="register-exec.php">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <th>Email </th>
  <td><input name="email" type="text" class="textfield" id="email" /></td>
</tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Check" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: before asking question at least try it out yourself when u got stuck or got an error then use stackoverflow for solution

Comment: I did but so many errors. That's why I am here.

Comment: edit your question and paste your actual code

Comment: where u define this `$email` ?

Comment: @devpro, i have corrected that.

Comment: and do u think this field `<input name="fname" type="text" class="textfield" id="fname" />` will give you email?

Comment: i think you php code doesn't match with the  html  code please paste the actual code which you got stucked or facing error

Comment: I edited the code so that why you see all this error. Where i have issues is at the last if statement. Everything is correct now.

Comment: is `register-exec.php` is the same file? what errors r u getting?

Comment: register-exec.php is the execution file.

Comment: and why this empty `if() {` ??

Comment: do u want to achieve, if email already exist print the error msg?

Comment: @devpro, i don't know what to do there.

Comment: I want to print, if email exist, print "Already in use" but if not print "Available"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic example of your code by using [MYSQLi Object Oriented](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php):

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(count($_POST) > 0){
    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    if($email == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email already in use';
        $errflag = true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $errflag = false; // if record not exist.
    }

    if($errflag){
        echo implode(",", $errmsg_arr); // if any error found print error array and use your error stuff like redirection as you are using.
    }
    else{ 
        echo "Available"; // else print Available message or use your stuff.
    }    
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

**Update:**

Don't know why are you using `$_SESSION` for print error, you just need to replace this statement with `$_SESSION` statement inside your `HTML`.

```
if($errflag){
   echo implode(",", $errmsg_arr); // if any error found print error array and use your error stuff like redirection as you are using.
}
else{ 
   echo "Available"; // else print Available message or use your stuff.
}
```

**Update 2:**

You just need to check error array is set or not and than use your condition like:

```
<?php
if(isset($errmsg_arr)){
    if(count($errmsg_arr) > 0){
        echo implode(",", $errmsg_arr); // if any error found print error array and use your error stuff like redirection as you are using.
    }
    else{
        echo "Available"; // else print Available message or use your stuff.
    }
}
?>
```

**Basic and Complete Example:**

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

require_once('config.php');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$errflag = false;
$successflag = false;

if(count($_POST) > 0){
//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag

$email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

if($email == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email already in use';
    $errflag = true;
} 
else 
{
    $successflag = true; // if record not exist.
}

}

//$conn->close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login Form</title>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
if($errflag){
echo implode(",", $errmsg_arr); // if any error found print error array and use your error stuff like redirection as you are using.
}

if($successflag){
echo "Available";
}
?>
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="register-exec.php">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <th>Email </th>
  <td><input name="email" type="text" class="textfield" id="email" /></td>
</tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Check" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Side Note:**

Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, because `mysql_*` deprecated and closed in PHP 7.

Comment: i need to put the php on top of the html?

Comment: @NoreplyNoreply: hmm, yes.

Comment: I did that and it prints "Availble" onpageload.

Comment: u r the champion @NoreplyNoreply, always try to use error_reporting, debuging from the ist line, understand the logic than write the code.

Comment: well, if you think, this answer resolve your issue than mark as accepted this will help to others. @NoreplyNoreply

Comment: The problem is not solved. I need to post the form first before printing the result of the query. But your script prints the result of the query on page load.

Comment: Please do me one more favor, just write the check statement which i must use in html to execute this code. Thanks.

Comment: chk update in my answer. no need to use session check inside the html for error printing. @NoreplyNoreply

Comment: I have done as you directed but why does the script execute and print avaible before even filling the input field?

Comment: @NoreplyNoreply: because when you not use this check `if(count($_POST) > 0){` it will always return you available message because query execute as "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '' ", and this statement always return you available,

Comment: okay. What do I need to add here <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="register-exec.php">

Comment: Honestly, i did everything as you directed yet, it prints available on page load. Can you please update your answer and include the HTML exactly how i should use it. Please, i beg you.

Comment: no need to beg @NoreplyNoreply, please update your updated code, than i can chk it.

Comment: @NoreplyNoreply: check my update2, and replace this code with your html condition..

Comment: It no long prints on page load. now, what do i need to add inside the html to connect with the code on submit?

Comment: yes, just remove this code and use update 2 @NoreplyNoreply `<?php
if($errflag){
echo implode(",", $errmsg_arr);
}
else{ 
echo "Available";
} 
?>`

Comment: Honestly, you are making it difficult for a learner to understand. I told you that I am a novice yet you teach me like a professional. If the code is in the same page, then how can i call the code from the html, that's what i want.

Comment: @NoreplyNoreply: check "Basic and Complete Example" this will resolve your issue.